# How to recover the LTI system step response by the known output and input signals?

Tags: linear-systems, digital-filters, filtering, step-response

Having the input signal as a step-like pulse and the output as its distorted version after passing through the system:

[image]

is it possible to somehow recover the step response of the system?

In the Figure above some kind of exponential behaviour could be observed, so the only way that comes to my mind is to use multiplication of exponential models like $(1+A_1\cdot e^{-t/\tau_1})\cdot (1+A_2\cdot e^{-t/\tau_2})\cdot...$, but I'm not sure whether it is correct.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ to say whether the system in question is linear and time invariant.  Because a pedant may just answer "yes" (assuming the system is LTI), you may also wish to ask _how_ one may go about recovering the step response.

Comment: done, is it clear now?

Comment: It's good style to put all the important stuff into the body of the question, even if it reiterates the title itself.  But this is good enough to go on.

Comment: it remains to answer to my question by somebody))